# Efficient table structure for application logging

Tags: sql-server, table

Am using SQL Server as my RDBMS and i want to maintain some transaction of an auto run tool which will log some info on a daily basis. I need some suggestions how an efficient structure to be.

I mean single table will be an efficient one or two or more tables based on the transaction type (say for example success,failure).

If possible, explain with a simple scenario

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/managing-transaction-logs-in-sql-server/

Comment: from  DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE);
GO
you can check log space information of all databases.

Comment: The rules of normalisation still apply.  if you have complex log data you need complex log tables.  If it's a simple list of events a single table with a few columns will do.

Comment: It depends if your goals, load of the app and hardware that you have. Could you provide more details? I can give exmaple with our software - we use OLTP software - which generates around 12-15 k transactions a day (during business hours). We have 2 tables - one for quick insertion of transactions and second where all old transactions are stored. Each night new transactions are move to the second table.

Comment: According to my case there will be max of 100 - 1000 logs per day. So if i maintain two tables one will contain the current month logs and when next month reaches i will be moving those details to another table (historical data) . So the historical data will be matched with OLAP DATA CUBES for showing user about the logs .

Will it be an optimal one ?or Is there anything which was more optimal than this.

Answer (score 2):

1) The first thing you would need to figure out, what recovery model you should go with , i.e. decide accordingly as per the need between , FULL , BULK and SIMPLE recovery model.

Read here for configuring the same: [Choosing the Recovery Model for a Database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987(v=sql.105).aspx)

2) When you create a new database in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005, the data and log files have the following characteristics by default:

> Data: initial size 2MB; Autogrowth: by 1MB, unrestricted growth
>
> Log:  initial size 1MB; Autogrowth: by 10 percent, unrestricted
>   growth

Therefore the first thing you will need to look upon what is the default value you will like to give while setting up for first time.

Its better to test the activity first on test env, come up with a minimal amount of capacity planning to help define your initial size and a maximum size.

3) Once you have come up with a default values for log file, its recommended to monitor the usage of log file or track its growth:

There are various ways of doing that.

You can use below query and collect the results storing in a table over a period of time via SQL agent job:

```
SELECT name,
  size, -- in 8-KB pages
  max_size, -- in 8-KB pages
  growth,
  is_percent_growth
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'
```

or using `DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)`

4) If a database is configured with the Full or Bulk Logged recovery model, you should back up the transaction log regularly so it can be truncated to free up inactive log space. The backup can also be used (along with the database backups) to restore the database in the event of failure.

Therefore its better to choose you're defaults correctly in order to avoid lot of event changes in log that may hamper the performance.

Comment: I didnt mean the mdf and ldf log files. I just asked for keeping track of  an operation and saving the status in a separate table. For that am asking whether single or multiple tables will be a good one.